# what decimal separator is used by Double.tostring()?

Tags: java, android

Is `Double.tostring()` using the decimal separator of the current local or something that is fixed for all locales and implementations (ie: dot ".")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It always uses `.` as a decimal separator.

See the [java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)):
[image: screenshot of java documentation]

Comment: thanks, i try to find some doc about this, i didn't find

Comment: @PhilipCouling The `.` is specified in [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-).

Comment: in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double) their is nothing about decimal separator :(

Comment: aaah yes i didn't see it like this ! can you put the screen shot in your response and i will accept it ?

Comment: **Screenshots** are the last resort. Javadoc is **text**; and you should simply quote as such. See how I did it in my answer!

Comment: But if I'd want to go through plain text, then I wouldn't have to answer a question! In my screenshot I marked the text passages explaining whats actually asked for.

Answer (score 2):

The `Double.toString()` method code :

```
public String toString() {
    return toString(value);
}
```

invokes this static method :

```
public static String toString(double d) {
    return FloatingDecimal.toJavaFormatString(d);
}
```

The javadoc of it is refers to the use cases of the method and all refers to `.` character as separator between the integer and the decimal part :

> - If m is zero, it is represented by the characters **"0.0";** thus,
>     negative zero produces the result **"-0.0"** and positive zero produces
>     the result **"0.0"**.
> - If m is greater than or equal to 10-3 but less than 107, then it is
>     represented as the integer part of m, in decimal form with no leading
>     zeroes, **followed by '.' ('\u005Cu002E'), followed by one or more
>     decimal digits representing the fractional part of m**
> - If m is less than 10-3 or greater than or equal to 107, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be
>     the unique integer such that 10n ≤ m < 10n+1; then let a be the
>     mathematically exact quotient of m and 10n so that 1 ≤ a < 10. The
>     magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single
>     decimal digit, **followed by '.' ('\u005Cu002E'), followed by decimal
>     digits representing the fractional part of a**, followed by the letter
>     'E' ('\u005Cu0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal
>     integer, as produced by the method Integer.toString(int).

It doesn't say explicitly : the separator is `.` but all use cases of the `toString()` method of `Double` explicit the `.` character as separator. 
By deduction, we may so consider `.` as the character separator.

Comment: where you see this? reading "0.0" in the doc not mean "." will be used as a decimal separator. in the doc they say nothing about the separator

Comment: It doesn't say explicitly : the separator is `.` but all use cases of the toString() method of `Double` explicit the `.` character as separator. By deduction, `.` is the character separator.

Comment: yes i agree, but i don't understand why no doc say clearly without ambiguity that the decimal separator will be always '.'

Comment: @loki You are right on this point. It would be clearer to read it rather than deducing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you study the javadoc for Double.toString() you will find that it mentions the static method [Double.toString(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)):

> If m is zero, it is represented by the characters "0.0"; thus, negative zero produces the result "-0.0" and positive zero produces the result "0.0".
>
> If m is greater than or equal to 10-3 but less than 107, then it is represented as the integer part of m, in decimal form with no leading zeroes, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by one or more decimal digits representing the fractional part of m.
>
> If m is less than 10-3 or greater than or equal to 107, then it is represented in so-called "computerized scientific notation." Let n be the unique integer such that 10n ≤ m < 10n+1; then let a be the mathematically exact quotient of m and 10n so that 1 ≤ a < 10. The magnitude is then represented as the integer part of a, as a single decimal digit, followed by '.' ('\u002E'), followed by decimal digits representing the fractional part of a, followed by the letter 'E' ('\u0045'), followed by a representation of n as a decimal integer, as produced by the method Integer.toString(int).

And the javadoc for that method lists in great detail how the result of that call is build up. And it clearly expresses that you need to use a NumberFormat yourself if you want localized output.

Comment: the doc say: To create localized string representations of a floating-point value, use subclasses of NumberFormat. ... yes, i know about this ... but that not say if the Double.toString() will use '.' or the decimal separator defined in current locale

Comment: Well. It tells you that you need to do something to get a localized output. Conclusion: when you nothing, you do not receive localized output.

Comment: no i not agree, i m for exemple in french local and i want the localized russian format so the doc say clearly i need to use the subclasses os NumberFormat, but the doc never say that the current will use a '.' or ',' for the decimal separator